# remove duplicates characters from string in perl using substitution

Tags: perl

How to remove duplicates characters from string in perl? i tried it using /d but result not match as required.

I already tried:

```
$string="vvvviiiiiipppppppiiiiinnnnn";
$string=~tr/a-z/a-z/s;
print $string;
```

output: vipin, but I want: vipn

Answer (score 6):

```
my %uniq;
$string = join '', grep !$uniq{$_}++, split //, $string;
```

or

```
use List::Util ();
$string = join '', List::Util::uniqstr( split //, $string );
```

Comment: or this: `1 while $string=~s,((.).*)\2,$1,;`